# Magento 2: how to overide adminhtml phtml file

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

As I don't have implemented admin theme I have to override `/vendor/magento/module-payment/view/adminhtml/templates/info/default.phtml` file in my custom module.
how can I write my layout file to call this file?

I have copied `default.phtml` in my custom module

Answer (score 0):

You can override the payment info model. The example below is for overriding \Magento\Paypal\Block\Payment\Info which is used for PayPal. You first need to check which payment method you are applying for and then override it. See where the template is set in the parent class in: **\Magento\Payment\Block\Info::$_template**

```
<?php

    namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Block\Payment;


    class Info extends \Magento\Paypal\Block\Payment\Info
    {
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        protected $_template = 'YourNamespace_YourModule::info/default.phtml';

    }
```

Be sure to update the di.xml as well.

Comment: basically i am need to get payment title on admin order detail page which i already done in vendor theme to check ... but as u know we  have to overide it in child theme so i guess the method u mentioned will not work

Comment: My solution doesn't require an overriding theme. It's overriding in a custom module. Which payment are you referring to?

Comment: i  made a custom payment method  and i am getting its title from custom column  on order detail page

Comment: on sales order detail page in admin, I want to show  payment title of order form database